# String equality( == ) issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparator, equality-operator

I am getting undesired output when i compare the ajax response to a string.
My **backend** is **PHP**. It is an `echo 'SUCCESS'` that responds to the ajax call.
When i compare the response with `"SUCCESS"` it is giving a false output!

Let me attach a screenshot of the console watch window for clarity.

[image: Console screenshot]

Please help me with a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a leading space…!?

Comment: There are probably special characters. try triming the string

Comment: It does look like there is a space (`" "`) before the `"S"`

Comment: Character `U` looks a bit different

Comment: I think its due to the async execution. can you show me the ajax section of the code

Comment: it was a friggin space... But i had to go two rounds to check that! Don't have any idea where it crept in from. But, not from the echo because i tried trimming that first! thank you guys for helping me find out :) @ste2425 Trim in the JS code helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a space in the success written at the top (pinkish) one. Remove that. For checking give a space in the if condition. If it succeeds then that is the issue.

Comment: If this was the issue and it is resolved kindly, mark it as the answer :). Thanks